# Why we should write List and DetailedUser in the variable <variable type = "list&lt;DetailedUser" name="">

Tags: android-databinding

I don't understand this line of the code  why we have list and DetailedUser?

```
<data>
     //app class
 <import type = "com.androidistanbul.databindingdemo.layoutdetails.DetailedUser/>
 // java class
  <import type= "java.util.List"/>
 <variable 
    name = "userList"
    type = "detailedUser" /> // import class
<variable 
    name="userList"
    type = "list&lt;DetailedUser" />
 </data> 

// List index
 <TextView 
//   android:layout_midth = "wrap_content"
//   android:layout_height= "wrap_content" 
//   android:layout_marginTop = "8dp"
  android:text="@{userList[index].name +  "" + userList[index].surnane}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;` and `&gt;` are [html entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) and they represent `<` and `>`, respectively.

So `List&lt;DetailedUser&gt;` translates to `List<DetailedUser>`